# Mutate new column over a large list of tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have used the following code to split the below dataframe (df1) into multiple dataframes/tibbles based on the filters so that I can work out the percentile rank of each metric.

**df1:**

| name | group | metric | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | distance | 10569 |
| B | A | distance | 12939 |
| C | A | distance | 11532 |
| A | A | psv-99 | 29.30 |
| B | A | psv-99 | 30.89 |
| C | A | psv-99 | 28.90 |

```
split <-  lapply(unique(df1$metric), function(x){
                 filter <- df1 %>% filter(group == "A" & metric == x)
})
```

This then gives me a large list of tibbles. I want to now mutate a new column for each tibble to work out the percentile rank of the value column which I can do using the following code:

```
df2 <- split[[1]] %>% mutate(percentile = percent_rank(value))
```

I could do this for each metric then row_bind them together, but that seems very messy. Could anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  group_nest(group, metric) %>% 
  mutate(percentile = map(data, ~percent_rank(.x$value))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c("data", "percentile"))
```

Comment: This also works perfectly & actually with more groups will work better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No need to split the data here. You can use `group_by` to do the calculation for each `metric` separately.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(group == "A") %>%
  group_by(metric) %>%
  mutate(percentile = percent_rank(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
df1 <- subset(df, group == 'A')   
df1$percentile <- with(df1, ave(value, metric, FUN = percent_rank))
```