# Mutate percentile rank based on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I've previously asked the following question: [Mutate new column over a large list of tibbles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67737179/mutate-new-column-over-a-large-list-of-tibbles/67744001#67744001) & the solutions giving were perfect. I now have a follow-up question to this.

I now have the following dataset:

**df1:**

| name | group | competition | metric | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | comp A | distance | 10569 |
| B | A | comp B | distance | 12939 |
| C | A | comp C | distance | 11532 |
| A | A | comp B | psv-99 | 29.30 |
| B | A | comp A | psv-99 | 30.89 |
| C | A | comp C | psv-99 | 32.00 |

I now want to find out the percentile rank of all the values in df1, but only based on the group & one of the competitions - competition A.

Comment: Hey, Peter. I think I found the solution for your answer: https://www.statology.org/percentiles-in-r/. However, beforehand you should filter your dataset for only "comp A" in ```competition``` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could [`slice`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html) the rows where the 'comp A' is found `%in%` `competition`, then do a grouping by 'group' column and create a new column `percentile` with [`percent_rank`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ranking.html)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   slice(which(competition %in% "comp A")) %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(percentile = percent_rank(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just change `metric` to `competition` in the previous code? It would give you the percentile rank for all competitions, including A.

```
df1 %>% 
  group_nest(group, competition) %>% 
  mutate(percentile = map(data, ~percent_rank(.$value))) %>% 
  unnest(c(data, percentile))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` the `competition` and `group_by` `group`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(competition == "comp A") %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(percentile = percent_rank(value))
```